# How pyspark read different dateformat using json schema for a csv file

Tags: csv, datetime, pyspark

Is pyspark can read different dateformat using dateFormat argument in json schema of csv file?

```json
{

"name": "startdate",

"type": "date",

"dateFormat": "MM/dd/yyyy"

},

{

"name": "closedate",

"type": "date",

"dateFormat":"yyyy-MM-dd"

}
```

Using .option(dateFormat) only one format can read how to read other format dates.

(OR)

Without using dateFormat in schema it can read different format dates in a general way (general way - not included column names any date column name it can accept)

Answer (score 0):

With the assumption that you don't have that many many different formats, you can collect all possible date formats, then apply each of them to the actual string value, then pick the one that is not null using `coalesce`

```py
formats = [r['dateFormat'] for r in df.select('dateFormat').collect()]
# ['MM/dd/yyyy', 'yyyy-MM-dd']

possible_dates = [F.to_date('value', f) for f in formats]
# [Column<'to_date(value, MM/dd/yyyy)'>, Column<'to_date(value, yyyy-MM-dd)'>]

df.withColumn('v', F.coalesce(*possible_dates)).show()
# +----------+---------+----+----------+----------+
# |dateFormat|     name|type|     value|         v|
# +----------+---------+----+----------+----------+
# |MM/dd/yyyy|startdate|date|09/13/2000|2000-09-13|
# |yyyy-MM-dd|closedate|date|2000-09-13|2000-09-13|
# +----------+---------+----+----------+----------+
```